# Oracle adding randim amount if seconds to a date

Tags: oracle, date, random

I have a date that is always set to midnight i.e.    '07312021 00:00:00' how can I use dbms_random.value to add (1 second, 23:59:59) to that date.

Comment: Why would you use a random value? Do you want to remove 1 second (your example seems to be removing, not adding), or do you want a truly random interval added or subtracted?

Comment: My dates are all set to midnight I want to be able to add a random amount of seconds. I tried this and it doesn't work select  trunc(sysdate) + dbms_random.value( .0000000002, .0000115642) from dual;

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DATE '2021-07-31' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 86400))
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or

```sql
SELECT DATE '2021-07-31' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
                             FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 86400)),
                             'SECOND'
                           )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or

```sql
SELECT DATE '2021-07-31' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
FROM   DUAL;
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d700af/462)*